# Why did "Community" edit my answer?

Tags: support, editing

It seems that my answer here was edited by "Community":

[Read-only column in a SharePoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/read-only-column-in-a-sharepoint-list/12923#12923)

I don't get the point of the edit, but that's not my main concern.

What I don't understand is why this account is editing posts in the first place. The account's mission is explained here:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

Comment: Based on the edit history I would say that the edit was proposed by an anonymous user and then accepted. Since the original proposer does not map to an account on the site, the edit will be marked as community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [that post's revision history](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/12923/revisions), you'll see that an anonymous user [suggested this edit](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/538), and James Love approved this suggestion. Since per definition, anonymous users have no account, these edits are owned by the community user.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, can confirm my above comment.

It seems that a new feature that would enable anonymous edit was tested some time ago. Your answer was edited during that time by some unlogged user, then the edit was approved. As said, since the original edit proposer does not map to an account on the site, the edit was marked as community.

You can find further reference here:
[Community♦ user edit: How does it know what to edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75472/community-user-edit-how-does-it-know-what-to-edit) and 
[Diff is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75377/diff-is-hard-lets-go-shopping)